# How do I split an array into two if one of the elements is a nil?

Tags: arrays, ruby, split, null

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array that I want to split into two, in which the first array will be either the letter "a" or "b" and the second array will be everything else, so I have this

```
arr1, arr2 = data_col.map { |x| a, b, c = x.partition(/^[ab][[:space:]]+/i); [b.strip, a + c] }.transpose
```

However, this fails if one of the eleemnts in teh array is nil.  How do I account for that and force two nil elements to be in teh resulting arrays?  THat is, if the original array is

```
["A bcd", nil, "B 123"]
```

the resulting arrays would be

```
["A", nil, "B"], ["bcd", nil, "123"]
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly check for it

```
arr1, arr2 = data_col.map do |x| 
  if x
    a, b, c = x.partition(/^[ab][[:space:]]+/i)
    [b.strip, a + c] 
  else
    [nil, nil]
  end
end.transpose
```

There is no smart way of doing `nil` propagation here.

---

And if you are cool with `""` as resulting elements, try this

```
arr1, arr2 = data_col.map { |x| a, b, c = (x || "").partition(/^[ab][[:space:]]+/i); [b.strip, a + c] }.transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the non-nil elements will always need to be split at the space, you can do away with the partition and regex testing and just do this:

```
>> a = ["A bcd", nil, "B 123"]
>> a.map { |e| e ? [e.split.first, e.split.last] : [nil, nil] }.transpose
=> [["A", nil, "B"], ["bcd", nil, "123"]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  If the input is '["C abc", nil, "B abc"]', using your function above the result is two arrays, one with '["C", nil, "B"]'.  I don't want to split the leter "C" into its own array, only the letters "a" or "b".

Comment: That would have been useful information. I was working from the assumption as I stated above. Perhaps you could have provided sample data that would have included the counter-example. Glad you got an answer that works.